# Saving Scrape-results into pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am using the following code to scrape some information of different pages of Google Scholar using Selenium and Beautiful Soup.

I can print all the scraped information but I can't save the results into one Dataframe for export.

How do I save the results (Title, Author, Link, Abstract) for each result of the search?

```
# Dataframe initialisieren
data = {
        "Titel": [],
        "Link" :[],
        "Authoren" : [] ,
        "Veröffentlichungsjahr" : [],
        "Abstract" :[] 
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


# Ort wo Chromedriver gespeichert ist (lokal)
PATH = '/Applications/chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

# URL aufrufen
driver.get('https://scholar.google.de/')
time.sleep(5)

#Searchbar finden und ausfüllen
search = driver.find_element_by_id('gs_hdr_tsi')
search.send_keys('"circular economy"AND "Dlt" AND "Germany" AND "Sweden"')
time.sleep(5)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

## Anzahl Ergebnisse --> /10 ist die Anzahl der Klicks auf "weiter"
Anzahl = driver.find_element_by_id('gs_ab_md').text
x=re.findall(r'\d+', Anzahl)[0]
# y mal auf "Weiter" klicken lassen
y = int(int(x)/10)+1
print("Seitenanzahl:", y)
i=0

for i in range(2): #y
    # Schranke einbauen, damit Selenium solange pausiert bis Ergebnisse geladen sind

    page_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
        
    for item in soup.select('[data-lid]'): 
            try: 
                print('----------------------------------------') 
       # print(item) 
                print(item.select('h3')[0].get_text()) 
                title = item.select('h3')[0].get_text()

                print(item.select('a')[0]['href'])
                link = item.select('a')[0]['href']

                print(item.select('.gs_a')[0].get_text()) 
                author = item.select('.gs_a')[0].get_text()

                txt = item.select('.gs_a')[0].get_text()
                print(re.findall(r'\d+', txt)[0])

                year = re.findall(r'\d+', txt)[0]
                print(item.select('.gs_rs')[0].get_text()) 

                abstract = item.select('.gs_rs')[0].get_text()

                data_2 = {
                "Titel" : title,
                "Link" : link,
                "Authoren" : author,
                "Veröffentlichungsjahr" : year,
                "Abstract" : abstract
                }
                
                df_new = pd.DataFrame(data_2)

                df = df.append(df_new, ignore_index=True)

                print('----------------------------------------') 
            except Exception as e: 
                #raise e
                print('---')
    # Random Wartezeit (2-15 Sekunden), bis nächste Seite aufgerufen wird, um IP-Blocks zu verhindern
    
    w = random.randint(1,14)
    time.sleep(w)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_link_text('Weiter').click()
    except:    
        driver.quit()

    i+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create set the dataframe during the loop. The strategy is to collect records into a list of dictionary and the end, create your dataframe.

New code (search `# <- HERE`)

```
# Ort wo Chromedriver gespeichert ist (lokal)
PATH = '/Applications/chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

# URL aufrufen
driver.get('https://scholar.google.de/')
time.sleep(5)

#Searchbar finden und ausfüllen
search = driver.find_element_by_id('gs_hdr_tsi')
search.send_keys('"circular economy"AND "Dlt" AND "Germany" AND "Sweden"')
time.sleep(5)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

## Anzahl Ergebnisse --> /10 ist die Anzahl der Klicks auf "weiter"
Anzahl = driver.find_element_by_id('gs_ab_md').text
x=re.findall(r'\d+', Anzahl)[0]
# y mal auf "Weiter" klicken lassen
y = int(int(x)/10)+1
print("Seitenanzahl:", y)

records = []  # <- HERE
for i in range(2): #y
    # Schranke einbauen, damit Selenium solange pausiert bis Ergebnisse geladen sind

    page_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
        
    for item in soup.select('[data-lid]'): 
            try: 
                print('----------------------------------------') 
       # print(item) 
                print(item.select('h3')[0].get_text()) 
                title = item.select('h3')[0].get_text()

                print(item.select('a')[0]['href'])
                link = item.select('a')[0]['href']

                print(item.select('.gs_a')[0].get_text()) 
                author = item.select('.gs_a')[0].get_text()

                txt = item.select('.gs_a')[0].get_text()
                print(re.findall(r'\d+', txt)[0])

                year = re.findall(r'\d+', txt)[0]
                print(item.select('.gs_rs')[0].get_text()) 

                abstract = item.select('.gs_rs')[0].get_text()

                records.append({  # <- HERE
                "Titel" : title,
                "Link" : link,
                "Authoren" : author,
                "Veröffentlichungsjahr" : year,
                "Abstract" : abstract
                })

                print('----------------------------------------') 
            except Exception as e: 
                #raise e
                print('---')
    # Random Wartezeit (2-15 Sekunden), bis nächste Seite aufgerufen wird, um IP-Blocks zu verhindern
    
    w = random.randint(1,14)
    time.sleep(w)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_link_text('Weiter').click()
    except:    
        driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame(records)  # <- HERE
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                               Titel  ...                                           Abstract
0  Shifting infrastructure landscapes in a circul...  ...  … [Google Scholar] [CrossRef]; Kirchherr, J.; ...
1  Demand-supply matching through auctioning for ...  ...  … 12, 76131 Karlsruhe, Germany cPolitecnico di...
2  Using internet of things and distributed ledge...  ...  … The authors were able to show how a combinat...
3  The impact of Blockchain Technology on the Tra...  ...  … In the broader sense, Blockchain is a Distri...
4  Assessing the role of triple helix system inte...  ...  … depends upon the successful diffusion of sev...
5  Circular Digital Built Environment: An Emergin...  ...  … For example, when searching for articles rel...
6  [PDF][PDF] Phillip Bendix (Wuppertal Institute...  ...  … Stadtreinigung Hamburg (Germany): AI image …...
7  Waste Management–A Case Study of Producer Resp...  ...  … A similar study in Germany reported an inter...
8  Blockchain in the built environment and constr...  ...  … changes in regulation can facilitate industr...

[9 rows x 5 columns]

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 9 entries, 0 to 8
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column                 Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------                 --------------  -----
 0   Titel                  9 non-null      object
 1   Link                   9 non-null      object
 2   Authoren               9 non-null      object
 3   Veröffentlichungsjahr  9 non-null      object
 4   Abstract               9 non-null      object
dtypes: object(5)
memory usage: 488.0+ bytes
```

Now you can use `df.to_csv(...)` to export your data.

Comment: I had a problem with the outer loop `i` but this is an another problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape all articles without browser automation and using only `requests` and `bs4`. Have a look in the code snippet below at the `if` statement inside `while` loop to see how pagination could be implemented.

[Code and full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/using-selenium-and-beautiful-soup-together) to scrape and save to CSV all author articles:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml
import pandas as pd


def bs4_scrape_articles():
    params = {
        "user": "VxOmZDgAAAAJ",       # user-id, in this case Masatoshi Nei
        "hl": "en",                   # language
        "gl": "us",                   # country to search from
        "cstart": 0,                  # articles page. 0 is the first page
        "pagesize": "100"             # articles per page
    }

    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582",
    }

    all_articles = []

    articles_is_present = True

    while articles_is_present:
        html = requests.post("https://scholar.google.com/citations", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

        for index, article in enumerate(soup.select("#gsc_a_b .gsc_a_t"), start=1):
            article_title = article.select_one(".gsc_a_at").text
            article_link = f'https://scholar.google.com{article.select_one(".gsc_a_at")["href"]}'
            article_authors = article.select_one(".gsc_a_at+ .gs_gray").text
            article_publication = article.select_one(".gs_gray+ .gs_gray").text

            print(f"article #{int(params['cstart']) + index}",
                  article_title,
                  article_link,
                  article_authors,
                  article_publication, sep="\n")

            all_articles.append({
                "title": article_title,
                "link": article_link,
                "authors": article_authors,
                "publication": article_publication
            })

        # this selector is checking for the .class that contains: "There are no articles in this profile."
        # example link: https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=VjJm3zYAAAAJ&hl=en&cstart=500&pagesize=100
        if soup.select_one(".gsc_a_e"):
            articles_is_present = False
        else:
            params["cstart"] += 100  # paginate to the next page

    pd.DataFrame(data=all_articles).to_csv(f"google_scholar_{params['user']}_articles.csv", encoding="utf-8", index=False)


bs4_scrape_author_articles()

# part of the output:
'''
article #1
The neighbor-joining method: a new method for reconstructing phylogenetic trees.
https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&pagesize=100&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:u5HHmVD_uO8C
N Saitou, M Nei
Molecular biology and evolution 4 (4), 406-425, 1987

article #421
PHYLOGENETIC ANALYSIS IN MOLECULAR EVOLUTIONARY
https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&cstart=400&pagesize=100&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:CYCckWUYoCcC
M Nei
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Scholar Author API](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-author-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to write a parser from scratch and maintain it over time, figure out how to scale a number of requests and how to bypass blocks from Google or other search engines.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qsl
import pandas as pd


def serpapi_scrape_articles():
    params = {
        "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
        "engine": "google_scholar_author",
        "hl": "en",
        "author_id": "VxOmZDgAAAAJ",
        "start": "0",
        "num": "100"
    }

    search = GoogleSearch(params)

    all_articles = []

    articles_is_present = True

    while articles_is_present:
        results = search.get_dict()

        for index, article in enumerate(results["articles"], start=1):
            title = article["title"]
            link = article["link"]
            authors = article["authors"]
            publication = article.get("publication")
            citation_id = article["citation_id"]

            print(f"article #{int(params['start']) + index}",
                  title,
                  link,
                  authors,
                  publication,
                  citation_id, sep="\n")

            all_articles.append({
                "title": title,
                "link": link,
                "authors": authors,
                "publication": publication,
                "citation_id": citation_id
            })

        if "next" in results.get("serpapi_pagination", []):
            # split URL in parts as a dict() and update "search" variable to a new page
            search.params_dict.update(dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(results["serpapi_pagination"]["next"]).query)))
        else:
            articles_is_present = False

    pd.DataFrame(data=all_articles).to_csv(f"serpapi_google_scholar_{params['author_id']}_articles.csv", encoding="utf-8", index=False)


serpapi_scrape_articles()

# part of the output:
'''
article #1
The neighbor-joining method: a new method for reconstructing phylogenetic trees.
https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&pagesize=100&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:u5HHmVD_uO8C
N Saitou, M Nei
Molecular biology and evolution 4 (4), 406-425, 1987
VxOmZDgAAAAJ:u5HHmVD_uO8C

article #421
PHYLOGENETIC ANALYSIS IN MOLECULAR EVOLUTIONARY
https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&cstart=400&pagesize=100&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:CYCckWUYoCcC
M Nei
None
VxOmZDgAAAAJ:CYCckWUYoCcC
'''
```

There's also a dedicated [Scrape historic Google Scholar results using Python](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-historic-google-scholar-results-using-python/#organic_results) blog post of mine that scrapes historic 2017-2021 Organic, Cite Google Scholar results to CSV, SQLite.

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.